# OOB Forecasting UI?

Tags: opportunity, standard-objects, forecast, forecasts-collaborative

I am not looking for any tips on building out a custom UI.

We plan to implement `Collaborative Forecasts` in my org, and want to avoid some of the mistakes of the previous build-out. There was *a ton* of customization that we didn't need to do, so now we are trying to go back to using as much Out Of the Box functionality as possible.

The data model part is easy. We're going to use `Opportunity`, `OpportunityLineItem`, `ForecastingItem`, etc. This model:

[image: Forecasts Objects]

Before I spec out an interface to work with this data model, is there any OOB front end functionality I should look at? My google-fu seems to be letting me down.

Comment: It's fine if the answer is no, I just want to make sure I cover my bases and don't miss something obvious.

Comment: You should be given a Forecasts tab that is driven off of your opportunity stages, and role-heirarchy (I think).

Comment: @JesseMilburn If you can dig up some screen shots I would definitely up-vote that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attached an image of the OOTB UI for Collaborative forecasting. (Shameless company plug included :) )

[image]

It is driven off of Forecast Category and Forecast heirarchy (Setup => Forecasts => Forecasts Hierarchy):

[image]

Be sure that your users have `Allow Forecasting` selected on their user record.